# Eclipse PyDev error message "compiled extension"

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In Eclipse, I have the following Console output

```
Logfile: File "C:\temp2\file1.log", line 1
Testimplementierung: File "A:\TestSafety\file2.py", line 222
```

Both paths are shown as hyperlinks.

When I click these hyperlinks in Eclipse Kepler, the files are openend in the Python Text Editor (this is what I want).
When I click these hyperlinks in Eclipse Luna or Mars, it works for the second file. For the first file, I get a dialog "The definition was found at: C:\temp2\file1.log (which cannot be opened because it is a compiled extension)"

Whats going wrong here?

Note: A:\TestSafety is my Eclipse Project. C:\temp2 is outside of my Eclipse workspace. Somebody told me I should add a "Link to existing source" into my Eclipse project, which seemed to work for a file, now it is broken again and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I've found the solution:
Open Window -> Preferences, goto PyDev -> Editor -> Code Style -> File Types, look for "Valid source files (comma-separated)" and append ", log".

The file extensions listed in this filed are evaluated by `FileTypesPreferencesPage.java:getDottedValidSourceFiles()`, which is called by `PythonPathHelper.java:isValidSourceFile()`, which is called by `PyGoToDefinition.java:doOpen()`, which is the method raising the error message.

Now my *.log file opens when I click on a hyperlink to it in the Text-Editor.